# InkWell onTap issue regarding "context"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing a news application in flutter using this article below. Everything works fine but in the last step I run into an issue with InkWell's onTap function because of "context."

Inside my code below I surrounded my "context" error with *** *** just for show.

I am going to show three total files.

https://nabendu82.medium.com/flutter-news-app-using-newsapi-2294c2dcf673

HomePage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_job_portal/news/model/article_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_job_portal/news/services/api_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_job_portal/news/components/customListTile.dart';

class HomeNews extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeNewsState createState() => _HomeNewsState();
}

class _HomeNewsState extends State<HomeNews> {
  ApiService client = ApiService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("News App", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: client.getArticle(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Article>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Article> articles = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: articles.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                    customListTile(articles[index], ***context***)
                //     ListTile(title: Text(articles[index].title))
                // customListTile(
                //       articles[index],
                //       context
                //     )

                );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

customListTile

```
// import 'dart:js';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_job_portal/news/model/article_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_job_portal/news/pages/articles_details_page.dart';

Widget customListTile(Article article) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
          ***context***,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ArticlePage(
                    article: article,
                  )));
    },
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black12,
              blurRadius: 3.0,
            ),
          ]),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          article.urlToImage != null
              ? Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(article.urlToImage),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
                ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            child: Text(
              article.source.name,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(
            article.title,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have access to a `BuildContext`. The quick solution, pass `context` to the `customListTile` method like so:

```
Widget customListTile(BuildContext context, Article article)
```

However, the best design practice would be to make a `CustomListTile` class that extends a `StatelessWidget` or a `StatefulWidget` rather than a function. Then you will have access to the `BuildContext` within the widget.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added BuildContext context in the parameters of the function which solved one file's issue. Now I just have the second issue of   ```  body: FutureBuilder(
        future: client.getArticle(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Article>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Article> articles = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: articles.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                    customListTile(articles[index], ***context***) ```

Comment: pass `context` to `customListTile`. `customListTile(articles[index], context)`